# Select all meshes with similar dimensions

Tags: mesh, objects

I have a large number of meshes similar in overall shape, but with slightly different dimensions, and completely different orientations and locations. For this example, do the following (or enough of it to get the idea, as it is tedious):

1. Create an icosphere, subdivided at least 2 times
2. In edit mode, select an edge, and separate it
3. Repeat for every edge

If you enable viewing edge lengths you'll find that the edges are not all the same lengths. Some are longer/shorter than others, but you'll find that there are groups of edges that have the same length.

In my project, I have done something similar, except I had created the sphere, inset all faces and removed the centre triangles, then selected the two faces to either side of the sphere's original edge lines, extruded outwards, then separated each edge. Basically made the edges 3D instead of just lines.

Given that every mesh is oriented differently, and that there are almost 500 individual meshes, is there a way for me to select one mesh, then find all other meshes that have the exact same dimensions? Essentially, I want to select all similar meshes so I can group them and count how many of each mesh there are. For example, I'd find that there are 100 of a `2.0 x 0.1 x 0.1 m` mesh, 50 of a `2.1 x 0.1 x 0.1 m` mesh, 75 of a `1.9 x 0.1 x 0.1 m` mesh, and so on.

I'm hoping my need isn't too obscure for a tool or add on to exist for

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is select all the elements and go to *Edit Mode*, now just select all edges or vertices of one of the repeating meshes, then click on menu above *Select > Select Similar > Area*.